# HTML+CSS+JS dynamic selected text highlighting color change

Tags: html, css, highlight

I use an HTML page to render some console output. The content of this page is pretty simple:

```html
<div>
    <span style="color: #0cc;">Checking random configurations</span><br>
    <span style="color: #0cc;">Installing new setup</span><br>
    ...<br>
    <span style="color: #0cc;">Done setup</span><br>
    <span style="color: #0cc;">Start</span><br>
    <span style="color: #c00;">ERROR</span><br>
    done.
</div>
```

I would like to customize the way the selected text is highlight (user selected text using the mouse) so that the foreground color becomes the background color and the background color becomes the foreground color.

I could not manage to find my way using CSS `highlight` property which sets the color to be used for highlighting the whole selection.

Is there a simple and portable way (HTML and/or CSS and/or java-script) to make the highlight color change regarding the current text's foreground and background colors?

EDIT:

The rendered text can be styled in multiple ways. As you can see in the example, some text is red, some other cyan, .. and many other formats are not given in the example.

From the user point of view, I would like the text selection highlight to be adapted to the selected text (i.e.: the portion of red text should be highlighted red/black (fg/bg), the later portion of cyan text should be highlighted cyan/black).

The `::selection` let me select the highlight FG and BG color but this is for the whole section. How can I embed it into the `span` so that I can customize the highlight on a per-portion basis?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change the text selection background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453410/how-to-change-the-text-selection-background-color)

Comment: If you want to change the text's parent background color, you will need to resort to JS

Comment: It is of great help, but how can I embed it into my `span` so that the highlight is specific to the selected text's color?

Comment: To wrap the selected text in a span you would need js - [this might give you some ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328718/how-to-wrap-surround-highlighted-text-with-an-element#answer-6328851)

Comment: If all those spans will only ever contain these color inline styles, and you know all relevant colors upfront - then you could probably do it purely via your stylesheet, `span[style="color: #0cc;"]::selection {...} span[style="color: #c00;"]::selection {...}`

Comment: What defines the various background colors?

Comment: You talk of the highlighted text being formatted according to the background color - I can't see where the background color is defined anywhere.

Comment: Yes, but what do you want the highlighted text color to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify things by having CSS variables set where they need to be and on selection just exchange the color and background colors:

```html
<style>
  span {
    --bg: black;
  }
  
  span {
    color: var(--color);
    background: var(--bg);
  }
  
  span::selection {
    background: var(--color);
    color: var(--bg);
  }
</style>
<div>
  <span style="--color: #0cc; --bg: pink;">Checking random configurations</span><br>
  <span style="--color: #0cc;">Installing new setup</span><br> ...
  <br>
  <span style="--color: #0cc;">Done setup</span><br>
  <span style="--color: #0cc;">Start</span><br>
  <span style="--color: #c00;">ERROR</span><br> done.
</div>
```

Note: this is not a total solution because I've just used a blanket white for background where it isn't explicitly defined. Given the very small set of properties that can be set on a ::selection pseudo element I cannot at the moment see how to pick up an inherited or existing background color using only CSS. But I leave this part-answer here in case it is at least partly useful.

Comment: Actually after some time of thinking your optimization is great as it avoids dynamic style computing. However, for it to work, the développer must be the provider of the data and be able to change the span format .. thank you for your help!

Comment: The CSS variables can be set in a stylesheet, they don’t have to be in the span itself.

Comment: Yep, definitely! I meant that as I convert the vt100 text to HTML content I can embed the colors in the span and provide a style sheet which renders the text selection properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) and [A Haworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10867454/a-haworth) for your precious help.

I also cane up you the following solution which I post here for history purpose. This solution computes the style definition dynamically.

```js
/** Default text foreground color. */
let default_color = "#fff";
/** Default text background color. */
let default_background = "#000";

function build_highlight_style(e, target)
{
    let color = e.style.color;
    let background = e.style.background;

/* If there is no explicit color change, then we keep the default highlight
 * style defined in the parent. */
    if (color === "" && background === "") {
        return ""
    }

    /* Define a custom style for the current element. */
    let style = [];
    style.push("span[style='" + e.getAttribute("style") + "']" + "::" + target + " {");

    if (color !== "") {
        style.push("    background: " + color + ";");
    }else{
        style.push("    background: " + default_color + ";");
    }

    if (background !== "") {
        style.push("    color: " + background + ";");
    }else{
        style.push("    color: " + default_background + ";");
    }

    style.push("    text-decoration: inherit;");
    style.push("}\n");

    return style.join("\n");
}

function setup_highlight_selection()
{
    let generated_styles = [];

    /* Create custom text selection highlight style for all `span` tags from
     * the container. */
    const content = document.getElementById("content");

    for (let ek in content.children) {
        const e = content.children[ek];

        if (e.nodeName != "SPAN") {
            continue;
        }

        style_str = build_highlight_style(e, "selection");
        if (generated_styles.indexOf(style_str) < 0) {
            generated_styles.push(style_str);
        }

        style_str = build_highlight_style(e, "-moz-selection");
        if (generated_styles.indexOf(style_str) < 0) {
            generated_styles.push(style_str);
        }

        style_str = build_highlight_style(e, "-webkit-selection");
        if (generated_styles.indexOf(style_str) < 0) {
            generated_styles.push(style_str);
        }
    }

    /* Add a new `style` tag to the document. */
    style = document.createElement("style");
    style.innerHTML = generated_styles.join("");
    content.appendChild(style);
}
```

```html
<body onload="setup_highlight_selection();">
<div id="content">
    <span style="color: #0cc;">Checking random configurations</span><br>
    <span style="color: #0cc;">Installing new setup</span><br>
    ...<br>
    <span style="color: #0cc;">Done setup</span><br>
    <span style="color: #0cc;">Start</span><br>
    ...<br>
    <span style="color: #c00;">ERROR</span><br>
    <span style="color: #0cc;">Done</span><br>
</div>
</body>
```